# How to snipe a message that is deleted 2 messages before

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have this bot in my server where it has a clear command, and whenever someone says something that is kinda inappropriate, they use the clear command. But the thing is, you can't snipe the message as the clear command deletes itself and the message.

```
snipe_message_author = {}
snipe_message_content = {}

@ult.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
  snipe_message_author[message.channel.id] = message.author
  snipe_message_content[message.channel.id] = message.content
  await sleep(60)
  del snipe_message_author[message.channel.id]
  del snipe_message_content[message.channel.id]


@ult.command()
async def snipe(ctx):
    channel = ctx.channel 
    try:
        snipeEmbed = discord.Embed(title=f"Last deleted message in #{channel.name}", description = snipe_message_content[channel.id])
        snipeEmbed.set_footer(text=f"Deleted by {snipe_message_author[channel.id]}")
        await ctx.send(embed = snipeEmbed)
    except:
        await ctx.send(f"There are no deleted messages in #{channel.name}")
```

if you are still confused by what i mean heres an example

*someone messages in the channel*

*same person does $clear 2, which clears the clear message and the message before it*

*someone uses the snipe command but nothing returns, as the snipe command cannot snipe the message before the clear command*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly.
If you clear multiple messages at once (for example with `channel.purge`) the `on_message_delete` listener *will not* get triggered.
Instead the `on_bulk_message_delete` listener will get triggered and returns the list of messages that were deleted.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=on_bulk_message_delete#discord.on_bulk_message_delete

If you set up another listener to get the second to last message in the list (the last one in the list being the clear command itself) and pass that into your snipe variables it should work.

Something like this maybe?

```py
@ult.event
async def on_bulk_message_delete(messages):
    #gets the last message of the list, excluding the clear command itself
    message = messages[-2]

    snipe_message_author[message.channel.id] = message.author
    snipe_message_content[message.channel.id] = message.content
    await asyncio.sleep(60)
    del snipe_message_author[message.channel.id]
    del snipe_message_content[message.channel.id]
```